# Counterparty.io: Is it possible to create wallet via API?

Tags: bitcoin

I want to create a counterparty wallet by using API. Blockchain.info has a create wallet API. I prefered to use similar one. https://blockchain.info/api/create_wallet

I already read counter party's API document but it does not seem to provide it. http://counterparty.io/docs/counterpartyd/#sign-tx

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the source for the webwallet [here](https://github.com/CounterpartyXCP/counterwallet) and the address code is [here](https://github.com/CounterpartyXCP/counterwallet/blob/master/src/js/components/address.js)

Its a javascript app all run in the browser, on a high level the app only reads, verifies and transmits valid counterparty protocol transactions and there is no api like what Blockchain.info offers at this time.

You can use the [python reference client](https://github.com/CounterpartyXCP/counterpartyd) for creating your own api.

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious answer. As far as I searched, counterpartyd is a one of federated node services, isn't it? I may have to prepare sufficient hardware spec for the node. It is very hard work for me. I expected that I can create a new wallet and send asset to someone by using the public system provided by counterparty. (hostname is devtest.counterparty.io)

Comment: nodes are not resource intensive.  If you download the bitcoin blockchain it will take a lot of time but you can probably connect the wallet or counterpartyd to a blockchain service.